# How to avoid second order sql injection attack when using database data with fgetc( stdin) in c++

Tags: c++, sql-injection, fgetc, secure-coding

```
std::string sQuery;
char ch= NULL;
ch = fgetc(stdin);
if(ch != EOF)
{
    sQuery += ch;
}
```

checkmarx is complaining about the code saying that fgetc element gets database data and  element value flows through the code without being sanitizes or validated and is eventually used in database query method

Comment: Note that `ch` needs to be an `int` in order to reliably test for `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing the DB query dynamically with untrusted data will make your code vulnerable to Second Order SQL Injection (and SQL Injection in general). To mitigate this risk, utilize a parameterization approach and frameworks such as [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html) can help you with this:

```
char ch= NULL;
ch = fgetc(stdin);
if(ch != EOF)
{
   QSqlQuery parametarizedQuery;
   parametarizedQuery.prepare("Select * from Table1 where column1 = :ch");
   parametarizedQuery.bindValue(":ch", ch);
}
```